# data binding of collections

Tags: c#, data-binding, collections

I just want to bind one collection to another one:
Lets say there is a

```
List<string> original = new List<string>();
```

and there is a

```
List<string> extended = 
           new List<string>(from curItem in originals select curItem + "_extension");
```

So the items of the extended are just the same than the original's but with an "_extension" at the end.

What I want is to bind the extended to the original, so that if the original becomes changed, the extended also changes.

I know I could use events and recreate the extended every time. 
But I think this is not efficient.

Edit:
Lets say: original is large and it is too exhausting to recreate the single elements of the extended and its also exhausting to create a single element at all.
So I want to have two lists (or collections) where on observes the other one and adds or removes the changes, like the data binding in Wpf, but adding an extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`BindingList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp) class on System.ComponentModel to achieve this... maybe it's like killing a fly with a hammer, but will serve to more complex examples.

I think you can make **an extension method** like this:

```
static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> Extensions(this IEnumerable<string> strs)
    {
        foreach (var str in strs)
        {
            yield return str + "_extension";
        }
    }
}
```

And you can use this on every `IEnumerable<String>`:

```
foreach (var x in original.Extensions())
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Comment: The BindingList<T> might be something I am looking for: it provides methods to report changes. But I still need to create my own extension of a List class for the **extended**, which can deal with the changes. Isn't there anything which is already implemented for that?

Comment: Take a look then, check this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23222/BindingList-Example

Comment: Thanks, but maybe I will use the ObservableCollection<T>.
On the other hand, I need no extend the List class of the extended, because I need a method which deals with the changed stuff...

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two different approaches:

1. To change `extended` when original changes.
2. Not to create `extended` at all, but create some class, that will
   add "_extention" on every query.

With bindingList the fisrt approach will be efficient enough.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private BindingList<string> original = new BindingList<string>();
    private List<string> extended = new List<string>();

    public BindingList<string> Original
    {
        get
        {
            return original;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Extended
    {
        get
        {
            return extended;
        }
    }

    public MyClass()
    {
        original.ListChanged += OnChanging;
    }

    void OnChanging(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.ListChangedType)
        {
            case ListChangedType.ItemAdded:
                extended.Add(original[e.NewIndex] + "_extention");
                break;
            case ListChangedType.ItemChanged:
                extended[e.NewIndex] = original[e.NewIndex] + "_extention";
                break;
            case ListChangedType.ItemDeleted:
                extended.RemoveAt(e.NewIndex);
                break;
            case ListChangedType.ItemMoved:
                string tmp = extended[e.NewIndex];
                extended[e.NewIndex] = extended[e.OldIndex];
                extended[e.OldIndex] = tmp;
                break;
            case ListChangedType.Reset:
                extended = new List<string>();
                foreach (string originalItem in original)
                {
                    extended.Add(originalItem + "_extention");
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The second approach will look like this: we create our own class witch contains link to `originals`

```
public class MyExtendedList : IEnumerable
{
    private List<string> original;
    public MyExtendedList(List<String> original)
    {
        this.original = original;
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new ExtendedEnum(original);
    }
}

public class ExtendedEnum : IEnumerator
{
    private List<string> original;
    private int position = -1;
    public ExtendedEnum(List<String> original)
    {
        this.original = original;
    }

    public object Current
    {
        get
        {
            return CurrentString;
        }
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        position++;
        return (position < original.Count);
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        position = -1;
    }

    public String CurrentString
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                return original[position] + "_extension";
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: check the `return Current;` line, I think it would be `return CurrentString`

Answer (score -1):

Make your own class:

```
public class MyClass
{
   private string _Item;
   public string Item 
   { 
       get { return _Item; }
       set 
       {
           if (_Item != value)
           {
               _Item = value;
               _ItemWithExtension = _Item + "_extension";
           }
       }
   }
   private string _ItemWithExtension;
   public string ItemWithExtension
   {
      get { return _ItemWithExtension; }
   }
}

var extended = 
           new List<MyClass>(from curItem in originals select 
                            new MyClass()
                            {
                                Item = curItem
                            }
                           );
```

Comment: How changing originals impact on extended?

Comment: @Amiram Korach: The problem with your solution is, that the new item becomes every time recreated when it becomes accessed. But I think this is exhausting too. I want the extended to observe the originals and just to add the new items just in time.

Comment: @Amiram: What if I do `extended[0].ItemWithExtension`? I will get *_extension_extension

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly, when you change the Item, the ItemWithExtension will be changed, but I'll improve my answer.

Comment: @Amiram Korach but I think, extended does not update, if originals becomes changed...

Comment: My suggestion is to use one list, not two. This single list will hold both values and the extended value is updated in the `set` clause.

Comment: I thought about this, but I think I don't want to have such a strong encapsulation. With two lists I would have a weaker one.